# Showing that $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(-\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are equivalent Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I'm working on a problem from R.S. Strichartz, "The way of Analysis":

> Can a Cauchy sequence of positive rational numbers be equivalent
>   to a Cauchy sequence of negative rational numbers?

Consider the sequences $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(-\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. I proved that they are both Cauchy and I am trying to apply the following definition to show they are equivalent:

For every $n$ there exists $m$ (depending on n) such that for all $k \geqslant m$, $\left|x_k-x_k^{\prime} \right| < \frac{1}{n}$.

My attempt:

Since $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(-\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are Cauchy, there is an $N_1$ such that $\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \right| < \frac{1}{2k}$ for every $n,m \geqslant N_1$ and an $N_2$ such that $\left|-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}\right|<\frac{1}{2k}$ for all $n,m \geqslant N_2$. Setting $N:=\max\big\{N_1,N_2 \big\}$, we can see that for every $m,n \geqslant N$, one has $$\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}-\left(-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}\right) \right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \right| \leqslant \left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \right|+ \left|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m} \right| < \frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k}=\frac{1}{k},$$ demonstrating that $\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \sim \left(-\frac{1}{n} \right).$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: My pleasure! $\,$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is good.

But here's an alternative *slightly* more direct way:

$|x_k - x'_k| = |1/k - (-1/k)| = 1/2k $.

So as long as $k > m \ge \lceil n/2 \rceil$ then $1/2k < 1/n$ and you are golden.